# How do you make a program sleep in C++ on Win 32?

Tags: c++, sleep

How does one "pause" a program in C++ on Win 32, and what libraries must be included?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
#include <windows.h>

Sleep(number of milliseconds);
```

Or if you want to pause your program while waiting for another program, use [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Error 2 error C3861: 'Sleep': identifier not found
//despite #include <windows.h>

Comment: Can you post your code and what compiler are you using? This works on my machine with GCC: #include <windows.h>

int main ()
{
    Sleep(1000);
}

Comment: Ok you have to have the modern <cmath> and so on first in line and the oldies after these, is that a rule? At least it worked with that order.

Comment: Maybe you had an include file that somehow prevented windows.h from being included. Which headers did you include? I can't reproduce your error with <cmath> / <math.h> / <windows.h>. Generally, I put system headers first.

Comment: Error include:#include <iostream> 
#include <windows.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, I can also run my sample program with those headers included in that order. I would suggest you put system headers at the top of your include list however, then standard headers and then your own custom / third party headers.

Comment: Is it OK to use very big values... like 24h ? Or are there some OS protections? (I know it's not the proper approch, dont tell me that)

Comment: @Sandburg Since it's not the proper approach, I haven't tried. I doubt many people have. So if you don't want to do a proper approach, you'll have to try it out yourself.

Answer (score 17):

In C++11, you can do this with standard library facilities:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(x));
```

Comment: Not recommended. If you call `sleep_for` and turn back the system clock by X minutes, sleep_for will sleep for X more minutes than what you specified in the call (at least on Windows, VS 2017). See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for.

Comment: Same for `sleep_until` used with `steady_clock`.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using boost, you can use the `thread::sleep` function:

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
boost::system_time time = boost::get_system_time();
time += boost::posix_time::seconds(1);
boost::thread::sleep(time);
```

Otherwise, you are going to have to use the win32 api:

```
#include <windows.h>
Sleep(1000);
```

And, apparently, C++0x includes this:

```
#include <thread>
std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
```

Comment: My gosh, that last line is ugly.

Comment: @Steve: My apologies.

Comment: I don't blame you, unless you're on the C++ standard committee ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the code above was tested on Code::Blocks 12.11 and Visual Studio 2012
on Windows 7.

**For forcing your programme stop or wait, you have several options :**

---

- **sleep(unsigned int)**

The value has to be a positive integer in millisecond.
That means that if you want your programme wait for 2 second, enter 2000.

Here's an example :

```
#include <iostream>     //for using cout
#include <stdlib.h>     //for using the function sleep

using namespace std;    //for using cout

int main(void)         
{
   cout << "test" << endl;
   sleep(5000);         //make the programme waiting for 5 secondes
   cout << "test" << endl;
   sleep(2000);         // wait for 2 secondes before closing

   return 0;
}
```

If you wait too long, that probably means the parameter is in second. So change it like that :

```
sleep(5);
```

For those who get error message or problem using sleep try to replace it by _sleep or Sleep especially on Code::Bloks.
And if you still getting probleme, try to add of one this library on the biggining of the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <windows.h>
```

---

- **system("PAUSE")**

A simple "Hello world" programme on windows console application would probably close before you can see anything. That the case where you can use system("Pause").

```
#include <iostream>    

using namespace std;   

int main(void)         
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

If you get the message "error: 'system' was not declared in this scope" just add 
the following line at the biggining of the code :

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

---

- **cin.ignore()**

The same result can be reached by using cin.ignore() :

```
#include <iostream>     

using namespace std;    

int main(void)         
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

    cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

---

- **cin.get()**

example :

```
#include <iostream>     

using namespace std;    

int main(void)         
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

---

- **getch()**

Just don't forget to add the library conio.h :

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <conio.h>    //for using the function getch()

using namespace std;    

int main(void)
{

    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

You can have message telling you to use _getch() insted of getch

Answer (score 1):

If you wish for the program to stay responsive while "paused", you need to use a timer event.

Comment: actually, in Qt, if you want your program to be responsive while paused from a piece of code that is executed from the main thread, you dont want the timeout event of your timer to happen in the main thread as well.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of program you are writing.

A console app can just call Sleep. A GUI app probably does *not* want to do this, as all the menus and widgets will go insensitive, and the app won't redraw itself during this period. Instead you need to do something like set yourself up a timer with a callback when it expires.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use a sleep function in your GUI if it is not provided by the framework you are working with.  This could create referencing problems to data (specially in a thread that is not the main thread).  This could freeze you GUI.  Its not just a question of sleeping for a short time , use waitmutexes if you need to do that.