# Slowing down a Visual C++ code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm using visual studio 2013.  When using my Arduino, I always used `delay()`. When first attempting this in C++, I found the function `_sleep()`. When I tried to use it, the compiler said that it was obsolete and to use `Sleep()` instead. When I tried to use the new Sleep function, that gave me errors still, because "identifier 'Sleep' is undefined." How do I make the program wait?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is the purpose of slowing down a program?

Comment: I want to have a text display one line at a time, as it displays in total more text than can fit on the screen.

Comment: Well, Sleep leaves you making assumptions about how fast the user can read. What if they get distracted? Generally, you do this by waiting for the user to press a key before going to the next screen.

Answer (score 0):

To use the `Sleep`, you have to include `windows.h`

```
#include <windows.h>

Sleep(number of milliseconds);
```

BTW: There is another question on stackoverflow like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252372/how-do-you-make-a-program-sleep-in-c-on-win-32)

Comment: I couldn't find that, but it is almost exactly what I was asking.