# How to reduce consumption of CPU in audio recording program (c++)

Tags: c++, cpu, cpu-usage, audio-recording, audio-capture

with help of the internet I wrote program that capture audio from microphone all time when it's running. Everything it's ok, but I need to reduce charge of CPU, because now it's about 30-35%.

```
int SoundCapture()
{
const int NUMPTS = 8000 * 1; // Sample rate * seconds
int sampleRate = 8000;
short int waveIn[NUMPTS];   // 'short int' is a 16-bit type; I request 16-bit samples below
                            // for 8-bit capture, you'd use 'unsigned char' or 'BYTE' 8-bit types
    HWAVEIN hWaveIn;
    WAVEFORMATEX waveform;
    WAVEHDR waveHeader;

waveform.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;  // simple, uncompressed format
waveform.nChannels = 1;                 //  1=mono, 2=stereo
waveform.nSamplesPerSec = 8000;
waveform.nAvgBytesPerSec = 8000;        // = nSamplesPerSec * n.Channels * wBitsPerSample/8
waveform.nBlockAlign = 1;               // = n.Channels * wBitsPerSample/8
waveform.wBitsPerSample = 8;            //  16 for high quality, 8 for telephone-grade
waveform.cbSize = 0;
MMRESULT result = waveInOpen(&hWaveIn, WAVE_MAPPER, &waveform, 0, 0, WAVE_FORMAT_DIRECT);
if (result)
{
    std::cout << "Something wrong with WaveOpen";
    std::cin.ignore(2);
    return 0;
}
// Set up and prepare header for input
waveHeader.lpData = (LPSTR)waveIn; //pointer to waveform buffer
waveHeader.dwBufferLength = NUMPTS;
waveHeader.dwBytesRecorded = 0;
waveHeader.dwUser = 0L;
waveHeader.dwFlags = 0L;
waveHeader.dwLoops = 0L;
waveInPrepareHeader(hWaveIn, &waveHeader, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

// Insert a wave input buffer
result = waveInAddBuffer(hWaveIn, &waveHeader, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
if (result)
{
    std::cout << "Something wrong with waveInAddBuffer";
    std::cin.ignore(2);
    return 0;
}
// Commence sampling input
time_t t = time(0);   // get time now
result = waveInStart(hWaveIn);
if (result)
{
    std::cout << "Something wrong with WaveStart";
    std::cin.ignore(2);
    return 0;
}


// Wait until finished recording
do {} while (waveInUnprepareHeader(hWaveIn, &waveHeader, sizeof(WAVEHDR)) == WAVERR_STILLPLAYING);
SaveWavFile(&waveHeader, t);
waveInClose(hWaveIn);
}
```

This is entire function that generate charge. How can I reduce it? Or maybe I can't? Use other capture method than WindowsAPI?

I tried to decrease sample per sec, but that didn't help much. I suppose it's something about buffer, but need any tip.

Cheers

Comment: I think the problem lies in the active waiting (do while loop), you are consuming useless cpu without any production. Try to change your code to use [events in windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sync/using-event-objects).

Comment: @JTejedor Thanks, you have right. I delete this loop and have minimal CPU charge. Program doesn't work properly now, but I know where look for solution.

Comment: You are welcome @dylo. As a workaround,I suggest sleep a few microseconds inside the loop until you find a proper solution.

Comment: @JTejedor: Microseconds? You've got a pretty decent idea how many samples you're processing per buffer, and that's typically far more than one. Even if you had just a single sample @ 44kHz, you'd sleep 25 us. For a mote realistic 1000 samples, you'd sleep 25000 microseconds, not "a few".

Comment: @MSalters. Microsecond is a misspelling, I meant to say millisecond instead. My fault :=|.

Comment: I add 1ms sleep in loop and now program work as it should, thanks @JTejedor.

Comment: @MSalters something it's wrong with our solution? Or it's only about unit?

Comment: @dylo: It was indeed about the unit, which made the sleep 1000x shorter, to the point of possible **increasing** CPU load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we have commented, the cpu consumption is due the active waiting in do-while loop. I suggested use [Event object in windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sync/using-event-objects). 
But as immediate solution, I suggest sleep a few milliseconds (do the relevant calculations to know exactly what is perfect time as @MSalters remark in his comments).

Based on [How do you make a program sleep in C++ on Win 32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252372/how-do-you-make-a-program-sleep-in-c-on-win-32/) a possible solution would be:

```
#include <windows.h>

//....
do {
   Sleep(X);
} 
while (waveInUnprepareHeader(hWaveIn, &waveHeader, sizeof(WAVEHDR)) == WAVERR_STILLPLAYING);
//....
```